# dreamweaver+coldfusion and relative paths

Tags: templates, coldfusion, dreamweaver, relative-path

How do I set the path in for coldfusion file/template so that files referenced by the template show up properly in DW?

let's say I have this setup

```
/file.cfm
/doc/file2.cfm
/include/header.cfm
/css/style.css
/js/mooQuery.js
```

If I reference the css+js files in header.cfm relative to root, it works on server, but not in DW.

If I reference the css+js files in header.cfm relative to /include/, it works on DW, but not on the server.

while I understand this and it's not the end of the world if DW doesn't use the css styling, I would like to be able to have it working from `/doc/file2.cfm` as-well.

I have some mild success using the base tag, but I need to target it for the server, so no help on the local drive (DW)

I would like to set up some very basic templating with coldfusion and have it work with dreamweaver. You'd think the different teams at Adobe would talk among themselves a bit.

Comment: Where specifically on your drive is the site defined within Dreamweaver compared to the web root folder of the server itself? As in, is the site defined as a sub-folder of the web root or at the web root? Please provide more info in your questions. Root relative paths do work within Dreamweaver, but you have to be make sure that the web root and the site root within Dreamweaver agree on where exactly the root it located.

Comment: I've got it as a sub-folder of root.

Comment: That's why it doesn't work in Dreamweaver. I don't develop in CF, but for PHP, I set up virtual hosts within Apache. Then there is no problem with links relative to the site root.

Comment: I thought that it was the sub-folder that is causing an issue within Dreamweaver. Over time I've found that I never use root relative links as too many times in the past I've had to move sets of files around that ended up breaking the root relative linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your live version is in a webroot but your local version is not. Dreamweaver's template system can deal with this but if you are trying to use a template system through ColdFusion files then the easiest approach is to simply use config files to manage values that are different between the two environments.

Setup a folder/file structure like this in your app folder...

```
config
|--live
|  |--config.cfm
|--dev
|  |--config.cfm
|--config.cfm
```

The config files in live and dev folders will have code similar to...

```
<!--- live config --->
<cfset request.cfg = {
  approot="/"
} />
```

and

```
<!--- dev config --->
<cfset request.cfg = {
  approot="/subfolder/"
} />
```

Additional struct keys can be added over time as necessary.

Then copy the appropriate config file for the environment into the parent config folder, and include it in your application or index file...

```
<cfinclude template="config/config.cfm" />
```

Your links then become...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#request.cfg.approot#class.css" />
<a href="#request.cfg.approot#index.cfm">Home</a>
<!--- etc --->
```